# Advanced Custom Fields. Flexible Content with Gallery subfield

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to build a Flexible Content which contains 4 possible Layouts (a description, a hero image, a gallery 1col and a gallery 2col). So far I can get the Description and Hero Image subfields to display just fine but the Gallery subfield wont show up on the page. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
<?php

            while(the_flexible_field("flexible_content")): ?>

                <?php if(get_row_layout() == "description"): // layout: Description ?>

                    <div class="proy-desc">
                        <h2><?php the_sub_field("text"); ?></h2>
                    </div>

                <?php elseif(get_row_layout() == "hero_image"): // layout: Hero Image ?>

                    <div class="proy-img">
                        <?php

                            $image = get_sub_field('image');

                            elseif( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                        <?php ?>
                    </div>

                <?php elseif(get_row_layout() == "gallery_50p"): // layout: Gallery 50p ?>

                    <div class="gallery">
                        <?php $images = get_sub_field('gallery_image_50p');
                           if( $images ): ?>
                              <ul>
                                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                              </ul>
                        <?php ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php elseif(get_row_layout() == "gallery_100p"): // layout: Gallery 50p ?>

                    <div class="gallery">
                        <?php $images = get_sub_field('gallery_image_100p');
                           if( $images ): ?>
                              <ul>
                                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                              </ul>
                        <?php ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your if statement. See below:

```
<?php elseif(get_row_layout() == "gallery_50p"): // layout: Gallery 50p ?>

                <div class="gallery">
                    <?php $images = get_sub_field('gallery_image_50p');
                       if( $images ): ?>
                          <ul>
                            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                          </ul>
                    <?php ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Change your section to this:

```
<?php elseif(get_row_layout() == "gallery_50p"): // layout: Gallery 50p ?>

                <div class="gallery">
                    <?php $images = get_sub_field('gallery_image_50p');
                       if( $images ): ?>
                          <ul>
                            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                          </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Your endif; was in the wrong spot. Everything else looks right, so give this a try.

Comment: Thanks @Joe - Tried it but still no sign of the gallery field. The "gallery" div don't show either so I guess it must be a bugg within the ADC Flexible Field and a Gallery Layout. I ended up using individual fields as I used to. All good this way :)